# backBarButtonItem(leftbackButtonItem) Style Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

[image]

I want change other UIBarButtonItem. but, retain buttonItemStyle...

I want the original buttonItemStyle... only change inner content

How make BackBarButtonItemStlye?

```
UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"section" style:<??? what is style?> target:self action:@selector(popView:)];
```

how i get the image button style?

plz.. help ^^

I never find this style.

api only support below style... not backbuttonstyle...

UIBarButtonItemStylePlain,UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered,UIBarButtonItemStyleDone,

`[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:backBarButtonItem];` is Not Want...

`[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:backBarButtonItem];` is Want..

because my custom buttonItem target, action is not nil...

my buttonItem is change custom item...

setBackBarButtonItem is only use default Action (now ViewController pop)

setLeftBarButtonItem is use any custom action

ex:

```
[ self navigationController] popToRootViewController];
[[self navigationController] popToViewController:[[[self navigationController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2] animated:YES];
```

big issue is not supported cocoa API backBarButtonItemStyle(image refrence)...

how to solve this problem?

only draw a illustrator backBarButtonItemStyle image?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `backBarButtonItem` of the parent view controller. Use `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain` as a style and UIKit will automatically use the back appearance.

Comment: I will make custom Action...
setBackBarButtonItem only use pop Action...
so, i use a setLeftBarButtonItem Method...

Comment: you comment means is make a something customButtonItem and use a setBackBarButtonItem:customButtonItem is right? but... not available does not work...

Comment: I don't quite understand. But, yes, that will make the button only pop the nav item. If you need to do any other action, use `viewWillAppear/Disappear:`.

Answer (score 0):

This style is not customizable. You need to create the bar button with some *image* that looks like the back button.

Comment: That's not exactly true, you can change the name of the button item with `backBarButtonItem`.

Comment: Yes. We can make the back button show any text. I am talking about the back button style here.